# How to save a bitmap image to the Android internal Storage?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to, after makes an bitmap from my relative layout, save the bitmap on internal storage. But, the image just get shorter on layout, and no file is saved.

```
Layout_to_Image layout_to_image;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        layout_to_image=new Layout_to_Image(MainActivity.this,relativeLayout);
        bitmap=layout_to_image.convert_layout();
        try {
            Date now = new Date();
            String nomeImagem = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString()+"/"+now+".jpg";
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
            File img = new File(nomeImagem, "croqui.jpg");
            FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(nomeImagem, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            outputStream.write(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Any logs? Or error trace?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your image in the external storage and not in an internal storage,
try to add this permission in your manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```